# Iteration Not Working As Intended

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a DO interation to loop a function I'm using to test for internet connectivity. The code is working fine, except that when one of the tests is satisfied the loop stops. I want this to continue in the background while the program is running. How can I get this to work?

```
Private Sub checkInternet()

    Dim InetChecker As Boolean
    InetChecker = CheckForInternetConnection()
    Do While LabelCount.Text <> ""
        Thread.Sleep(10)
        If InetChecker = True Then
            Dim image = My.Resources.greenbar
            PictureBox4.Image = image

        Else
            Thread.Sleep(10)
            Dim image = My.Resources.redbar
            PictureBox4.Image = image
            'NoInetConnError.Show()
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a BackgroundWorker on your form (you will find it in the Components section of the Toolbox).

In the Properties window set `WorkerReportsProgress` to `True` for your BackgroundWorker.

Insert the following code to your form

```
Private connected As Boolean

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) _
 Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    While True
        Dim online = CheckForInternetConnection()
        If online <> connected Then
            connected = online
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(online))
        End If
        Thread.Sleep(500)
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
 Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Dim online As Boolean = CBool(e.ProgressPercentage)
    If online Then
        PictureBox4.Image = My.Resources.greenbar
    Else
        PictureBox4.Image = My.Resources.redbar
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
 Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Start the background worker
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

Note that `Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork` runs on a separate thread and does not freeze your form while it is running.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to do something like this in a `Timer` and not in a loop.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  If CheckForInternetConnection Then
    PictureBox4.Image = My.Resources.greenbar
  Else
    PictureBox4.Image = My.Resources.redbar
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  It worked, however, it was causing the application to be unresponsive everytime the code ran.  So I'm gonna see if I can use the background work method suggested by @davidsleeps below.  Thanks again.

Comment: @KismetAgbasi Make sure you aren't calling the code too often.  In your posted code, you were sleeping for 10 ms between checks.  That's probably firing your CheckFor... method too often.  10-30 seconds might be more practical since you are just trying to display a status to the end user.  I looked at your CheckForInternetConnection code from your other question: google (or any website) may not appreciate what you are doing to them if you run that code every 10 ms.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that.  I will adjust the wait/sleep time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to .Net framework 3+ then you could use the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) class which essentially creates an interval (set at whatever length you require) which you can handle the tick event for. When the tick event is raised, you can do your internet connection check.

Modifying the MSDN example for your situation, you could do something like this:

```
'  DispatcherTimer setup
dispatcherTimer = New Threading.DispatcherTimer()
AddHandler dispatcherTimer.Tick, AddressOf dispatcherTimer_Tick
dispatcherTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0,0,1) ' Or however long you want
dispatcherTimer.Start()

Private Sub dispatcherTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Checks to see whether an internet connection is still available etc
    checkInternet()

    ' Forcing the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately, the dispatcherTimer control isn't available in the Toolbox.